# Nginx language url rewriting

Tags: url, nginx, rewriting

How can rewrite this :

https://www.mysite.org/dev/index.php?locale=en_US

To this :

https://www.mysite.org/en_US/index

Thanks.

Comment: will all URL's contain that prefix ? because it would be tricky if some do and some don't.

Comment: No necessary, I just want this on all urls.

Comment: are you using any sort of framework ? handling it from the framework routing system would be easier.

Comment: No, I do not use any framework